# How to send Ctrl-C kill signal in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal

In the terminal I've been using for years (ConEmu), I am able to stop the currently running command with Ctrl-C.

This does not work with the Windows Terminal running PowerShell.  Once I start a continuous command (like `ping -t 8.8.8`, which I use during internet outages to see when I have connection to the outside world again), I cannot kill it except by closing the terminal window.

How can I stop the current process from Windows Terminal PowerShell?

Comment: @PortMan Are you using the option to replace the default Windows console (conhost) with Windows Terminal, or are you opening Windows Terminal manually? There _was_ a bug related to the "system conhost replacement" feature not allowing signals to be passed through.

Comment: I'm opening Windows Terminal manually, but I also have to open cmd.exe manually.

AFAIK, I never did anything to replace conhost with the terminal.

I don't see any settings for that in the terminal app.